# Request Timeout in cast.Api.loadMedia()

Tags: google-cast, chromecast

I've got my Chromecasts whitelisted and was doing some sender and receiver app development.

Ran into this strange problem of a callback returning "Request timeout" after a second or two when after a few more seconds, the media started playing on the Chromecast device.

```
castApi.loadMedia(currentActivityId, loadRequest, launchCallback);
```

The status launchCallback returned was:

```
cast.MediaResult {
  activityId: "ao4hr3w1a1gw",
  status: null,
  success: false,
  errorString: "Request timeout"
}
```

This happens sporadically, depending on how fast the video load on the Chromecast device. But the timeout (probably 1 to 2 seconds) happens so quickly that it returns a failure about half the time. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I am having the same issue with our app. My guess is that it's an issue with the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

When it successfully runs your media (after initial timeout error message), do you get an updated successful message via your callback?

Comment: No, I don't. The media keeps playing and my callback never gets called anymore.

Comment: Do you see anything in the log on the receiver side? You can attach a debugger to it and monitor the console for log messages. It would be helpful to share your code (sender and receiver) if this problem persists and you need further help with debugging that.

Comment: Do I have to look for anything in particular in the console log?

Comment: Errors or anything that looks suspicious